# Normalizing not nested tree into nested with Normalizr

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, normalizr

I have to normalize two responses from the server and store them in my store using normalizr.
The first response gives me the sections, the second the posts. **Sections** have many **posts**. **One post** can only have **one section**.

First response (**sections**):

```
[
  {
    id: 10,
    title: "foo"
  },
  ...
]
```

Second response (**posts**):

```
[
  {
    id: 2,
    sid: 10, //id of the section
    title: "foo",
    text: "foo foo"
  },
  ...
]
```

I want to normalize the responses into this schema:

```
{
  entities: {
    sections: {
      10: {title: "foo", posts: [2, 5, 12, 152]},
      15: {title: "example", posts: [1, 8]},
      ...
    },
    posts: {
      1: {id: 1, sid: 15, title: "abc", text: "something"},
      2: {id: 2, sid: 10, title: "foo", text: "foo foo"},
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Since the response is not nested I don't know how to define the Schemas.

Answer (score 2):

May be you can do that with simple code? Without any library? oO

```
var posts = [ ... ]; // some posts here
var sections = [ ... ]; // some sections here
var schema = { entities: { sections: {}, posts: {} } };

for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    var section = sections[i];
    schema.entities.sections[section.id] = {
        title: section.title,
        posts: []
    }
}

for (var j = 0; j < posts.length; j++) {
    var post = posts[j];
    schema.entities.posts[post.id] = post;
    schema.entities.sections[post.sid].posts.push(post.id);
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer. Normalizr is for dealing with single JSON objects that need to be de-nested. You'd have to first mangle your responses together, then run it through normalizr. This answer is a much simpler solution.

Comment: @PaulArmstrong well, actually it makes sense when denormalizing. We have a rest api and our JSON is not deeply nested, but we prefer denormalized objects in ours react components. It would be great to have some generalized way for it